# OSX exported environment variables not inherited in child process

Tags: macos, bash, variables, export, environment

I suffer from really strange problem on Snow Leopard. In my terminal, I wrote two scripts:

First:

```
#script-1.sh
export MY_VAR="This is my variable"
```

Second script:

```
# script-2.sh, having +x permission
#!/bin/bash
echo $MY_VAR
```

In Terminal, if I source the script-1 and then call script-2 as a child process, no output is displayed:

```
$> source script-1.sh
$> echo $MY_VAR
This is my variable
$> . script-2.sh
This is my variable
$> ./script-2.sh

$>
```

Any idea what is wrong here? I tried the same scenario on Windows using Cygwin, and there it works as expected - on OSX, it seems, that the child process does not know `$MY_VAR` at all.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you didn't run `script-1.sh` in child process? I tried your example in 10.6.8 and 10.7.3 and it works properly. Command `source script-1.sh` is same as `. script-1.sh` and it runs script in same context. Exported variables are environmental variables and they are always copied to child process.

Only scenario when I was able to reproduce same output as you have is, when I omitted `export` from script-1.sh file.

Comment: I think `script-1.sh` is not being executed in child process. But I have found, that the following works as a workaround: `$> sh -c ". script-1.sh && ./script-2.sh"`

Comment: Your workaround is basically same as your example. Be aware of if script-1 fails it will not execute script-2.